# creating vector from 'if' function using apply in R

Tags: r, vector, apply

I'm tyring to create new vector in R using an 'if' function to pull out only certain values for the new array. Basically, I want to segregate data by day of week for each of several cities. How do I use the apply function to get only, say, Tuesdays in a new array for each city? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds as though you don't want `if` or `apply` at all.  The solution is simpler:

Suppose that your data frame is `data`.  Then `subset(data, Weekday == 3)` should work.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to use the R `if`. Instead use the subsetting function `[`

```
dat <- read.table(text="    Date    Weekday Holiday Atlanta Chicago Houston Tulsa
1   1/1/2008    3   1   313 313 361 123
2   1/2/2008    4   0   735 979 986 310
3   1/3/2008    5   0   690 904 950 286
4   1/4/2008    6   0   610 734 822 281
5   1/5/2008    7   0   482 633 622 211
6   1/6/2008    1   0   349 421 402 109", header=TRUE)
dat[ dat$Weekday==3, ]
```